# how to pass data from form made on LWC to visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, visualforce-component, lightning-web-components

I've been trying to connect paypal with salesforce using paypal api: "https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"> the problem, i'm not able to implement this api in lwc but i achieved it using visualforce and all it works very well. The problem, is i did my form on lwc and i want to pass de amount to pay to visualforce controller. i dont know how to connect both.

The idea, is when i finish the form and click in submit button, redirect to visualforce page with the amount i've wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to pass your values as a parameter to VF controller via webPage navigation. You just need to carefully prepare your complete url then you need to call window.open(url).